# didRangeBeacon not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

sI don't know if I miss the setup of my beacon. I try everything but the code doesn't work of me. My beacon is kontakt.io. I tried there sdk and there sample code, but still doesn't work.
here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import  <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
#import "KontaktSDK.h"

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <KTKLocationManagerDelegate,KTKActionManagerDelegate,KTKBluetoothManagerDelegate>

    @property (strong,nonatomic) KTKLocationManager * ktkLocationManger;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager * locationManager;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) KTKRegion * ktkRegion;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) KTKActionManager * actionManager;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) KTKBluetoothManager * bluetoothManager;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) KTKBeaconManager * beaconManager;
    @end
```

and my viewcontroller.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *beaconLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ktkLocationManger = [[KTKLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.ktkLocationManger.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if ([KTKLocationManager canMonitorBeacons])
    {
        KTKRegion *region =[[KTKRegion alloc] init];
        region.uuid = @"A77A1B68-49A7-4DBF-914C-760D07FBB87B"; // kontakt.io proximity UUID


        [self.ktkLocationManger setRegions:@[region]];
        [self.ktkLocationManger startMonitoringBeacons];


        self.bluetoothManager = [[KTKBluetoothManager alloc] init];
        self.bluetoothManager.delegate = self;

        self.beaconManager = [[KTKBeaconManager alloc] init];
        self.beaconManager.delegate = self;

        [self.beaconManager startFindingDevices];
    }


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.ktkLocationManger startMonitoringBeacons];

}

- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didChangeState:(KTKLocationManagerState)state withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (state == KTKLocationManagerStateFailed)
    {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong with your Location Services settings. Check OS settings.");
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didEnterRegion:(KTKRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Enter region %@", region.uuid);
    self.beaconLabel.text=@"enter";
}

- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didExitRegion:(KTKRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"Exit region %@", region.uuid);
    self.beaconLabel.text=@"exit";
}

- (void)locationManager:(KTKLocationManager *)locationManager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
{
    NSLog(@"Ranged beacons count: %lu", [beacons count]);
    self.beaconLabel.text=@"Range";

}
```

I tried everything just to work the didRangeBeacons: but failed multiple times.
Is there something that I need to setup or I just miss the code. Hoping for your advice or help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember about adding `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your project's Info.plist file? This is required in iOS 8.

In the Project Navigator (left sidebar), find the Info.plist file (it's in the Supporting Files directory), right click on it and select Open As > Source Code. Then, add this just before the `</dict>` line:

```xml
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app uses your location in order to blah blah...</string>
```

The description should give an explanation on why your application needs to access user's location data. The better the explanation you give, the bigger the chance the user will allow it, so choose wisely! (:

Comment: I already doing that @heypiotr. I would like to ask. didRangeBeacons: method need a wifi connection from beacon?

Comment: I get it now. When I turn off the airplane mode from iphone settings. It works but when I turn on, nothing happened. does every beacon need to turned off the airplane mode settings from phone?

Comment: Beacons use the low-energy Bluetooth 4.0, not WiFi. Airplane mode usually disables Bluetooth, preventing the phone from discovering beacons.